# Saving into post_excerpt or post_content

Tags: database

When importing a feed into a custom post type does it make any difference if I store the feed description in the post_excerpt field versus the post_content field? Is there some processing that gets applied via WordPress when I save content to any of those two fields?

Comment: There is no difference when saving to DB. The only processing difference is that `post_excerpt` will be wrapped in `<p>` element when displayed on frontend.

Comment: Also (in 3.4.x) post_excerpt is used for describing the attachment post type, but I am guessing you want for normal page/posts right?

Comment: I want to use it in a custom post type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in storing data into the `post_excerpt` field versus the `post_content` field.

If you look at the [source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L0) (line 2700) you will notice both `post_excerpt` and `post_content` won't be filtered.